Exercise on conditional expectation
i've got an exercise that i cannot solve properly. I am given $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$, $P[A]=\int_{A}f(x)dx$ for some density function $f: \mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty)$. I am asked to give an explicit formula for the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[X\vert \sigma(Y)]$ where X is an integrable random variable and $Y(w)=sin(w)$ is another random variable.
Due to our lecture the generated sigma-algebra $\sigma(Y)$ is given by the sets $\{Y\leq t \vert t \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e. $\{w\in \mathbb{R} \vert Y(w)\leq t \}$, so these sets should be $\cup_{k\in \mathbb{N}}[-0.5\pi + 2\pi k, \text{arcsin}(t)+2\pi k] $, right?
My idea was then to find the conditional expectation by the equation $\int_{B} Y d\mathbb{P} = \int_{B} sin(x)f(x)dx$, but i am not even sure if this is correct, but it would lead to something like $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} \int_{-0.5\pi +2\pi k}^{arcsin(t) sin(x)f(x)dx$ . But i am not sure about those things and whenever i find at least some similar exercises at the internet, the solution contains something like conditional densities or quite different formulas to calculate conditional expectations.
I am quite stuck with this exercise, so if anyone could help me out a little, that would be really great :)

This question is already answered here. In this case the answer could be written like this:
$$E[X|Y]=$$
$$=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(\arcsin(Y)+2k\pi)X(\arcsin(Y)+2k\pi)}{\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}[f(\arcsin(Y)+2k\pi)+f(-\arcsin(Y)+(2k+1)\pi)]}+$$
$$+\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(-\arcsin(Y)+(2k+1)\pi)X(-\arcsin(Y)+(2k+1)\pi)}{\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}[f(\arcsin(Y)+2k\pi)+f(-\arcsin(Y)+(2k+1)\pi)]}$$
Or like this:
$$E[X\mid Y](\omega)=$$
$$=\frac{\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}[f(\omega+2k\pi)X(\omega+2k\pi)+f(\pi-\omega+2k\pi)X(\pi-\omega+2k\pi)]}{\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}[f(\omega+2k\pi)+f(\pi-\omega+2k\pi)]}$$
